# How to assign & display index number for everyline, and choose first field value through index number in PS3, then feed this to next command

Tags: bash

I have this bash script:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
job=`cat example.txt`
lines=`cat example.txt | cut -d " " -f1`
for i in ${!lines[@]}; do echo "$i\t" ${job[$i]}; done
PS3="Select desired job-id to check current status: ENTER HERE!!! => "
select id in "${lines[@]}"; do echo "you have selected ${id}" ; echo "looking into ${id}" ; break
done
```

with this example.txt file:

```
53763958  4.01005  my_job  me_userid  r    2023-01-13T07:39:10.821  1
53763959  0.00000  your_job  you_userid  hqw  2023-01-13T07:37:29.525  1
53763961  0.00000  his_job  he_userid  hqw  2023-01-13T07:37:29.923  1
53763929  0.00000  her_job  her_userid  qw   2023-01-13T07:28:56.918  1
```

results in:

```
1) 53763958
53763959
53763961
53763929
Select desired job-id to check current status: ENTER HERE!!! => 1
you have selected 53763958
53763959
53763961
53763929
looking into 53763958
53763959
53763961
53763929
```

My desired result is:

```
1) 53763958  4.01005  my_job  me_userid  r    2023-01-13T07:39:10.821  1
2) 53763959  0.00000  your_job  you_userid  hqw  2023-01-13T07:37:29.525  1
3) 53763961  0.00000  his_job  he_userid  hqw  2023-01-13T07:37:29.923  1
4) 53763929  0.00000  her_job  her_userid  qw   2023-01-13T07:28:56.918  1

you have selected: 53763958-my_job
```

I will choose x) index and first field value (53763958 in this example) must be choosen as a vaiable for next command (echo "looking into ${id}")

Comment: You must make `lines` an array, where each element consist of one line. In your code, `lines` is a scalar, holding the complete text.

Comment: As the [bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bash) tag you used instructs "For shell scripts with syntax or other errors, please check them at https://shellcheck.net before posting them here.".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, put the entire file's contents into an array.

```
readarray -t lines < example.txt
```

and use this array to build the *menu*. You won't extract the first field until *after* a choice is made.

```
PS3="Select desired job-id to check current status: ENTER HERE!!! => "
select job in "${lines[@]}"; do 
    id=$(echo "$job" | cut -d " " -f1)
    echo "you have selected ${id}"
    echo "looking into ${id}"
    break
done
```

Comment: this is amazing....works seemlessly. can you please suggest how to add 3rd field value to echo "looking into ${id} - ${3rd field value}". please see my question above.

Comment: I solved it.. added additional variable.